# Can we change worksheet in function?

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to write a vba function that takes a range as an argument and returns some coefficients to the worksheet. But when I try to write anything to my worksheet from the function, I get an undefined value (#VALUE!). When I change function to macro(sub) and hardcode the arguments in the function, it allows me to set values in worksheet.

```
' these don't work
Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(4, 1) = x
Sheets("Sheet1").Range(4, 1) = x
```

Can you please give me a simple example of a function that takes a range of values as arguments, calculates something, and writes answers back to worksheet.

Comment: will this formula be accessed from a cell formula to return data to that cell or as a stand alone function that writes data to the sheet?

Comment: In case you are trying to define a UDF: it is not recommended to change other cells from within a UDF

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this function can be used like many of the inbuilt functions that are used within individual cells

```
Public Function TestMe(rangeX As Range) As String
    TestMe = "This is a test - " & rangeX.Value
End Function
```

but it will error if you try to affect other cells

This next method will need to be run as a macro either from a button or from running the macro manually.  This method assumes that it will be passed two single cell ranges.

```
Public Sub RunTest()
    'A1 and A2'
    Test2 Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, 1), Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(2, 1)
End Sub

Public Sub Test2(rangeX as Range, rangeY as Range)
    'write values out to A4 and B4'
    Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(4, 1) = rangeX
    Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(4, 2) = rangeY
End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

If what you want is a user defined function that returns more than one value, try using an array function.
An array function is entered by selecting a range of cells in a sheet, typing the function and pressing Ctrl-Shift-Enter.  The result is the function you typed is in each of the cells you selected, wrapped in {}

Your user defined function then needs to return an array of values
For example

```
Function MyArrayFunction(r As Range) As Variant
Dim cl As Range
Dim i As Long, j As Long
Dim v() As Variant

ReDim v(1 To Application.Caller.Rows.Count, 1 To Application.Caller.Columns.Count)
For i = 1 To UBound(v, 1)
    For j = 1 To UBound(v, 2)
        v(i, j) = i * j + r.Value
    Next
Next

MyArrayFunction = v
```

End Function

To use, select a range, say A1:B4, type `=MyArrayFunction(D1)`, press Ctrl-Shift-Enter
if D1 contains 0 result will be A1=1, B1=2, A2=2, B2=4, A3=3, B3=6, A4=4, B4=8